# Drawing diagonal line in a cell of a table in iTExt?

Tags: java, itext

I'm creating a table in **iText**, but I've a problem with a cell that could be divided by a **diagonal line**. Someone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be via an `onGenericTag` handler in a `PdfPageEvent`.

You give the contents of that cell a generic tag via `Chunk.setGenericTag(String tag)`, and set up a PdfPageEvent hanlder that will draw your line when that chunk is drawn.

Something like:

```
public class MyPdfPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
  public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, Rectangle rect, String tag) {
      PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
      canvas.saveState();
      canvas.setColorStroke(Color.BLACK); // or whatever
      // You can also mess with the line's thickness, endcaps, dash style, etc.
      // Lots of options to play with.
      canvas.moveTo(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());
      canvas.lineTo(rect.getRight(), rect.getTop());
      canvas.stroke();
      canvas.restoreState();
  }
}
```

Comment: hey Thanks, your answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well. The answer of @Mark Storer was helpful, in this case there was a cell of a table I used "PdfPCellEvent" to inherid this methods.

Thanks Mark!